# How can i compare two documents with word matching

Tags: web, comparison, document

I have my resume in doc format. Now i also have the job description in another doc format.

Is there any way , i can compare the docs like employer use for resume scanning to find the matching candidate

Comment: Please don't disqualify candidates for having resumes that don't match your predefined document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how they do it but you could always save a text version of your resume and then just write a script to pull out key words (either "not a stop word" or some list you explicitly give) via regexes.